# Insert Into Select multiple columns mysql

Tags: mysql, select

This query doesn't work, but individual queries inserting and selecting only one column do work:

```
INSERT INTO subdata (reggeduser,completed)
SELECT COUNT(u.email) FROM user AS u,COUNT(a.email) FROM application AS a
```

My end goal is this:

```
CREATE EVENT 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
STARTS '2016-12-12 00:00:00'
DO
INSERT INTO subdata (reggeduser,completed)
SELECT COUNT(u.email) FROM user AS u,COUNT(a.email) FROM application AS a
```

MySQL version used is `5.6.19-67.0-log`.

The error thrown is a simple #1064 Invalid Syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way, using variables:

```
SET @count1=0;
SET @count2=0;
SELECT COUNT(email) INTO @count1 FROM user;
SELECT COUNT(email) INTO @count2 FROM application;
INSERT INTO subdata (reggeduser,completed) VALUES (@count1, @count2);
```

Comment: The statements need to be inside a transaction at the appropriate isolation level if we want to be sure that the results are consistent.

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into subdata (reggeduser,completed) values
(
    (select count(u.email) from user        as u)
   ,(select count(a.email) from application as a)
)
```

---

Demo

```
create table subdata     (reggeduser int,completed int);
create table user        (email int);
create table application (email int);
```

---

```
insert into subdata (reggeduser,completed) values
(
    (select count(u.email) from user        as u)
   ,(select count(a.email) from application as a)
)
```

> 1 row(s) affected